# Using if(isset($_POST['submit'])) does not submit

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to make a delete button that open a modal to confirm the delete action (deleting posts)
When I click delete inside the modal nothing happens,
what is the problem?
here is the form code

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default btn-primary" style="color: #580024;" >
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close
  </button>
</form>
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $query = mysqli_query($this->con, "UPDATE posts SET deleted='yes' WHERE id='$id'");
   header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
 }
  ?>
```

Comment: can`t I do the delete process without forms and inputs?

Comment: Your statement that "nothing happens" means your code not deleting or the page "not" loading on button press? Try removing the redirect and checking again. I'm guessing you have a query error but you can't see it because of the redirect. Also if you redirecting to the same page you don't need that part of the code.

Comment: the delete button does submit, you can test it by putting an echo "here" in the isset function and commenting out the query and header